# How to remove margins from compose-desktop Button?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

Having this:

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable
fun ButtonTest() {
    Button(onClick = {}, Modifier.border(1.dp, Color.Red)) {
        Text("test")
    }
}
```

produced UI looks like this:

[image]

How can I remove white margins at top and bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in kotlin community slack archive: https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/C01D6HTPATV/p1664901247640999

[image]

Comment: Im super not glad with this. Idk how almost after 2 years of your question almost no one got annoyed by this.